# Extracting the Row Number of the Nth Occurence

Tags: r

Is there an easy way (or any way) to extract the row number of the nth occurrence of some condition in R in a data frame? Let's say I have a data frame with 30 columns, all the same types of values. I want to extract the row number from each column in which the 2nd occurrence of some condition happens. It's quite simple to extract the count of all rows that match the condition, but I can't figure out how to extract the row that matches the nth occurrence of the condition.

I was flirting with the idea of converting the data frame into a list, adding a cumulative sum column in each of these data frames, and taking the row index once the cumulative sum hits 4 (for example). But, there's got to be an easier way than this.

Example:

```
#create data
example<-replicate(30,rnorm(n=10))

#pseudo code
which(row of 2nd negative number for each column)
print row number that satisfies condition for each column
```

If I could figure out how to extract the nth occurrence I assume I can just use apply(). I've tried almost everything and searched all over and still am having quite a hard time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The amount of functions I tried within an apply() function is embarrassing when looking at how simple what you just submitted is. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: The part that I was missing the whole time was the [2] at the end. Other than that I had everything else. Forgot the easiest part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have several columns we want to check for values less than zero (I've used 5 columns to keep the output short but the solutions work for an arbitrary number of columns).

```r
set.seed(123)
example <- replicate(5, rnorm(n = 10))
```

We can use `which` to find the row numbers of values less than 0 in a single column

```r
which(example[, 4] < 0)
#> [1]  2  8  9 10
```

But we are only interested in the second instance a value was less than zero

```r
which(example[, 4] < 0)[2]
#> [1] 8
```

You can use `sapply` to do this for all columns (as originally provided by [@d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128934/d-b) in the comments)

```r
sapply(as.data.frame(example), function(x) which(x < 0)[2])
#> V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
#>  2  8  2  8  2

sapply(1:NCOL(example), function(i) which(example[,i] < 0)[2])
#> [1] 2 8 2 8 2
```

Or if you prefer a `tidyverse` approach you could use `dplyr::summarise_all`

```r
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(example) %>% summarise_all(function(x) which(x < 0)[2])
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     2     8     2     8     2
```